# Database name after underscore in connection string is being ignored

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am trying to do something which I believe is very simple.
I have a connection string which I am grabbing from a database. When I create a new instance of SQL connection it looks (when I debug and look at the object) like it is populating the db connection string properly. However, the error messasge I get makes me think that all the information after the underscore in the database name is being eliminated.

Code Ex:

```
Database db = new SqlDatabase(ConnectionString); // Connection string appears correct
DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("StoredProcName");
DataSet approverDataset = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand); // when this executes, exception is generated
```

When I run this code I'm greeted with the following exception message:
The server principal "testdb_psidentity" is not able to access the database "testdb" under the current security context

Here's my connection String:

```
DataSource=testserver.com;Database=testdb_ps;Trusted_Connection=false;uid=testdb_psidentity;pwd=testpwd
```

I've tried changing this to:

```
DataSource=testserver.com;Database=[testdb_ps];Trusted_Connection=false;uid=testdb_psidentity;pwd=testpwd
```

And while that seems to get the full name of the database, it also seems to be looking for a database with those brackets in the name as well.  As I get this error:
Cannot open database "[testdb_ps]" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'testdb_psidentity'.

However, I can log connect to the database using that login/password in SQL server management studio.

Any way I can make it accept the database name testdb_ps database name? I'm unable to simply change the database name because I don't have access to this, and I've been told that changing the database name simply will not happen.

Comment: does your user "testdb_psidentity" has connect/execute permissions on the database? if you are not sure about it, you may check it by going to ->right-click on database -> properties -> permissions -> select the user and check under explicit tab...

Comment: Sadly, when I right click on the DB, I don't have access to see this.

Comment: Reach but try putting the datasource in the syntax [testserver.com] or [testserver].[com].  And you are sure the name of the source is testserver.com  (not testserver).  See the name in SMSS

Comment: your username doen't have the permission to access the database. Check the permissions

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting quotes around the connection string, I think it is interpreting the underscore as a delimiter.

Depending on how you use it use quotes or

```
&quot;
```

Comment: Did your quote mess up? How do you mean? I've tried using it as a string variable. I haven't tried hard coding it but that's generally frowned upon in our coding standards.

Comment: Typically we put our connection strings in the web.config or app.config file. This why we don't really have an issue with the '_' character. If you have to get the connection string from a database though, maybe try writing it out to a string first and sending that string in. The `&quot;` is used in some scenarios when you can't just type the character, but if you do a string literal in c# you shouldn't need it

Comment: Just a suggestion, but if this database has been around for awhile then I would assume other apps use it? If so you could look and see how they are going about it.

Answer (score 0):

Are u able to connect to the database through SQL server management studio?

Try

1. Disabling firewall
2. Using IP address
3. Using sql server instance name explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the entity classes using the wizard. This way you will get the encoded connection string in app.config